# ORA-12704: character set mismatch in case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting the mismatch error even though both are NVARCHAR2(50). they appear fine separate.

```
select O.MEDIC_NO
,O.PRO_TIN
,CASE WHEN O.MEDIC_NO IS NULL THEN '' ELSE O.PRO_TIN END AS PRO_TIN_PREVIOUS
from Q119 o
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is likely the string literal isn't NVARCHAR2(50). Each branch of the CASE needs to return a value of the same type.

```
select O.MEDIC_NO
,O.PRO_TIN
,CASE WHEN O.MEDIC_NO IS NULL THEN cast('' as NVARCHAR2(50))
      ELSE O.PRO_TIN END AS PRO_TIN_PREVIOUS
from Q119 o
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The first item in a CASE WHEN's THEN list determines the character set/datatype in use for the rest of the list. Here it's the empty string (probably a VARCHAR2), and your O.PRO_TIN isn't the same charset/datatype (isn't compatible)

Try casting your empty stirng to the same type as O.PRO_TIN, or try swapping the logic around so O.PRO_TIN is first (`CASE WHEN x IS NOT NULL THEN O.PRO_TIN ELSE '' END`)